# Find all records without a field

Tags: django, mongodb

I have mongoDB with an object totals in collection. In some objects dissapeared fields value
I have a function which can add field value to objects
So how can I make a query which returns all records where it's not value

```
pd = PaymentDoc.objects(
        date__gte=datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
        #totals__value what should be here?
    )
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want all objects that don't have any value in the `totals` field?

Comment: Use $exists:false operator.

Comment: @Danoram  Yes, absolutely right